# Confused About Change of Integration Limits in Convolution Proof

Tags: real-analysis, integration, laplace-transform, convolution, change-of-variable

My textbook has proved the convolution theorem as follows:

> **Theorem**
>
> If $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are two functions of exponential order (so that their Laplace transforms exist), and writing $\mathcal{L} \{ f \} = F(s)$ and $\mathcal{L} \{ g \} = G(s)$ as the two Laplace transforms, then $\mathcal{L}^{-1} \{ FG \} = f * g$, where $*$ is the convolution operator.
>
> **Proof**
>
> Suppose that $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are two functions of exponential order.
>
> Then
>
> $$ \mathcal{L} \{ f(t) * g(t) \} = \int_0^\infty e^{-st} \int_0^t f(\tau) g(t - \tau) \ d\tau \ dt ,$$
>
> by the definition of Laplace transform and convolution.
>
> Rewriting of this double integral to facilitate changing the order of integration gives
>
> $$\mathcal{L} \{ f(t) * g(t) \} = \int_0^\infty \int_0^t e^{-st} f(\tau)g(t - \tau) \ d \tau \ dt$$
>
> And then integrating with respect to $t$ first gives
>
> $$\mathcal{L} \{ f(t) * g(t) \} = \int_0^\infty \int_{\tau}^\infty e^{-st} f(\tau) g(t - \tau) \ dt \ d\tau = \int_0^\infty f(\tau) \left\{ \int_{\tau}^\infty e^{-st} g(t - \tau) \ dt \right\} \ d\tau$$
>
> [...]

I'm wondering how/why the limits of integration on the second integral changes from $0$ and $t$ to $\tau$ and $\infty$?

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sketching a graph for the region of integration is a big help.

Note that the region of integration for   $$ \int_0^\infty \int_0^t e^{-st} f(\tau)g(t - \tau) \ d \tau \ dt$$
is a triangular region below that line $\tau=t $ where t goes from $0$ to $\infty$ and $\tau $ goes from $0$ to $t$

When you change the order of integration on the same region, starting  with $\tau$, the region is on the right side of the line $t=\tau$ so you have $\tau$ going from $0$ to $\infty$ and $t$ goes from $\tau$ to $\infty$

Thus you have $$  \int_0^\infty \int_{\tau}^\infty e^{-st} f(\tau) g(t - \tau) \ dt \ d\tau  $$